# Error: NameError: name 'parent' is not defined

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to pass context value but getting above error.

***.xml**

```xml
<page string="Devices" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','device')]}">
          <field name="device_ids" >
            <tree editable="bottom" >
              <field name="product_id" />
              <field name="quantity"/>
              <field name="state" />
              <button string="Procurement" name="%(purchase.purchase_rfq)d" context="{'origin':parent.name}" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','not in',['nostock'])]}" type="action" icon="fa-shopping-basket" class="fa-shopping-basket" groups="stock.group_stock_manager"/>
            </tree>
          </field>
</page>
```

When i am using `parent` in `field` it works fine. I need to call it in `button`.

How can i do this?

Comment: you can try to use **name** without **parent**

Comment: @Karara, it's One2many field, i updated my question.

Comment: I think you can make computed/related field and put it in the tree (invisible), the you can put your context without parent.